# How can I use github with private tokens?

Tags: ios, git, github, token

I am working on building an iOS app as part of a team, for which we have an extremely limited budget, so we can't use github with private repos. However, we need to be able to have the Google login API, but we don't want to risk exposing our private tokens to the rest of the world. Is there any way in Xcode or github itself to get around this issue?

Comment: Why use github? Use your own server to host the git repository.

Comment: You could look at tools like [git-crypt](https://github.com/AGWA/git-crypt) but I'm not aware of anything built into either Xcode or github that does what you want.

Comment: Bitbucket has free private git repo hosting.

Comment: If one of you has a consistent connection (e.g. a desktop computer) you can set that up as everyone's remote.

Comment: Well we wanted the code to be open source, so that's why we wanted github. Git-crypt is unfortunately not an option because we don't have have admin privileges.  As for bitbucket, it limits you to 5 users unfortunately